# are mysql queries like (INSERT , SELECT) belong to any languages?

Tags: php, mysql

Are queries  or statements like (`INSERT` and `SELECT`)belong to any language LIKE(`SQL` OR `PHP`) or is it just a style of code(writing or entered into) the databases like `MySQL`.
Thank u :)

Comment: um its SQL.....

Comment: it is belongs to SQL

Comment: These are very basic SQL operations. There are several SQL standards which standardize different operations. On top some DBMS add their proprietary fetures (INSERT and SELECT are non of those). Also see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE` etc are part of sql. And almost every Database Package support **sql as a query language** to communicate with database.

[Reference](http://www.sqlcourse.com/intro.html)

Comment: the L in SQL = langaugae. and "And almost every language support sql as a query language to communicate with database." makes little sense